# Why are there open and closed pull request in gcc's mirror repository in github?

Tags: github, gcc

I know gnu doesn't use github for code storage or collaboration, but there is still a mirror repository in github. I understand that this could be used for viewing code conveniently, but there are also PRs (pull requests), which confuses me.

Since gnu use mailing list to submit patches, why are there PRs? Also there are some PRs closed, but never merged, and some are open. It seems that someone is managing this, why?